# How to flex between one and two children per row with a max. width of 1080px in total

Tags: flexbox

Using Flexbox, I'm trying to craft a layout that will have one child per row on mobile devices, and up to two children per row on bigger screens.

I'm trying to achieve this using the `flex-basis` property.

This works until I set the maximum width of the container to 1080. Then everything stays in one column.

Last time I checked, 540 x 2 = 1080 but as you'll see in the code below, two children will not fit on one row unless the maximum width of the container is 1120px.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why that's happening, so would appreciate someone explaining as the end result is either a container that is too wide for my design, or everything stuck in one 540px column.

Here's the code:

```
.container {  
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        padding: 0px;
        border: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        max-width: 1120px;
    }
  
    .header {
        background-color: #efe9b4;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 0px;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
        overflow: hidden;
        flex-basis: 1080px;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }

    .content_01 {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        flex-basis: 540px;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
  
    .content_02 { 
        background-color: #fffdeb;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        flex-basis: 540px;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
  
    .content_03 {
        background-color: #efe9b4;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        flex-basis: 540px;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
```

There're actually six 'content' children to allow for the proper background colours, but they all need the same properties apart from that.

Incidentally, I had the design going in CSS Grid but it simply refused to flex between one and two children per row, which I'm guessing is because the layout required the header and footer to span two columns, thus setting two columns as the minimum I could have.